# Keyboard module installed but not detected

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, keyboard

I am on MacOS and have installed the `Keyboard` module. It took a while to install the first time, but eventually it finished and, when I try running my script in Pycharm, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard'`.

The first time I installed it was within Terminal with pip3. After that I tried with Git Clone and it told me that Keyboard was alredy installed. I know this to be correct because when I enter `help("modules")` into a Python window, it shows up on the list.

Edit: I have also tried restarting Pycharm

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most probably in PyCharm's interpreter. You may try to reset the interpreter to your latest python3.

In this link (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html), please see the section "Changing the project interpreter in the project settings".

Hope it works!

Comment: My interpreter is set to Python 3.8 and I don't have any other options to choose from. I was also able to successfully import tkinter, time, and math. And I have tried importing "**k**eyboard" and "**K**eyboard" now

Comment: I encountered the same situation as yours before, but it was in a different module. Anther quick suggestion to figure out the problem source (is it from PyCharm's setting, or from the newly installed Keyboard module): save the python code that used Keyboard module's function, and run this .py file directly from terminal as "python3 yourscript.py". If it works fine in terminal, then the problem is definitely from PyCharm's setting.